# How can I disable Microsoft ads?

Tags: windows-10, advertisements

My Windows 10 Home Edition computer frequently pops up various ads for Microsoft services. For example, just now it popped up a dialog that said "Make logging in even easier! Install Microsoft Authenticate" or something like that. How can I disable this sort of activity?

Comment: Windows 10 isn't operation system anymore in sense of "you are the owner", that progressively taking out control from owners and becoming more like Android locked downed OS. It becomes more like advertisement station with built in A.I. that your training for Microsoft. While there are still possibility to take a little control back, Microsoft forcibly will revert most of tweaks back on update since they feel like they are the owner, not you. If you really want to still use this "OS", you can get server's version which is more expensive but at least giving more control over it "genius" software

Answer (score 10):

There are many places within Windows 10 that can potentially be the source of those advertisements, but I believe that the modification you want is as follows:

1. Navigate to **Settings** > **System** > **Notifications & actions**
2. Select **Off** for `Get tips, tricks, and suggestions as you use Windows`

That being said, with just a bit more time and effort you can be much more thorough when it comes to eliminating obtrusive Windows 10 advertisements by implementing the following changes:

> ## Disable Lock Screen Ads
>
> 1. Navigate to **Settings** > **Personalization** > **Lock screen**
> 2. Set the `Background` to **Picture** or **Slideshow** instead of Windows Spotlight
> 3. Select **Off** for `Get fun facts, tips, and more from Windows and Cortana on your lock screen`
>
> ## Stop Suggested Apps From Appearing in the Start Menu
>
> 1. Navigate to **Settings** > **Personalization** > **Start**
> 2. Select **Off** for `Show suggestions occasionally in Start`
>
> ## Turn Off Ads from Windows Welcome Experience
>
> 1. Navigate to **Settings** > **System** > **Notifications & actions**
> 2. Select **Off** for `Show me the Windows welcome experience after updates and occasionally when I sign in to highlight what’s new and suggested`
>
> ## Turn Off Ads in File Explorer
>
> 1. At the top of the `File Explorer` window click on **View**
> 2. Click on the **Options** button on the right side of the ribbon
> 3. In the subsequent `Folder Options` window click on the **View** tab
> 4. Scroll down the list of `Advanced settings` and uncheck **Show sync provider notifications**
> 5. Click the **OK** button to close the window
>
> ## Remove Ads From the Windows Ink Workspace
>
> 1. Navigate to **Settings** > **Devices** > **Pen & Windows Ink**
> 2. Select **Off** for `Show recommended app suggestions`

Together, these adjustments should eliminate the most prolific built-in Windows 10 advertisements.

---

Sources:
[Disable Advertising in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/80413-disable-advertising-windows-10-a.html)
[How to Disable All of Windows 10’s Built-in Advertising](https://www.howtogeek.com/269331/how-to-disable-all-of-windows-10s-built-in-advertising/)