# How to remove Microsoft software promotions from Windows Search results

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, microsoft-edge, advertisements, windows-10-v1909

Since a few weeks, every time I search for my default internet browser (Google Chrome) I also get the suggestion to download the new Microsoft Edge browser, which annoys me (Ssee the screenshot. Translation of the recommendation in the screenshot: "Recommended: Microsoft Edge - New. Download now."). I cannot find a way to get rid of such (Microsoft) promotions from the Windows Search results.

[image: the screenshot]

Is there a universal way (I can imagine setting a registry key or the likes) to remove this, and feature, promotions/ads from the Windows Search results?

I already turned off the options "Ocassionaly show suggestions in Start" and "Get tips, tricks, and suggestions as you use Windows". However, turning those options off does not remove the promotions (as stated above) from the Search results.

Windows version: Windows 10 Home, version 1909, build 18363.900

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1348757/how-can-i-disable-microsoft-ads

Comment: @Ramhound I reviewed the suggested answer of that post. I already have deselected options such as "tips and suggestions about Windows" and "Occasionaly show suggestions in Start" that are stated as solutions in that post. However, those options do not remove these promotions from the Search results. I will update the question with the details that I already turned off said options.

Comment: I can’t read the text in the screenshot so I can’t tell if it’s making that suggestion or actually finding the results on your machine.  Microsoft pushed an update that installs Microsoft Edge over Windows Update.  Questions are expected to be in English and that includes screenshots (or they are supposed to be translated).

Comment: It is making a suggestion. It translates to "Recommended: Miscrosoft Edge. Download now" and when I click on the result the old Microsoft Edge browser is opened and loads https://www.microsoft.com/nl-nl/edge? providing a link to download the new browser

Comment: [That’s probably Cortana if your still using 1909](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-remove-advertising-windows-10)

Comment: The settings for Cortana in that post are not available to me. When I search for the Cortana settings using Search(/Cortana I guess) and I click on some setings, only the Settings' home page is opened... 
However, if there will be an Windows version update soon, I will let this rest and I will try to fix this in the new update. Thanks for the help and pointers.

Comment: Try a third-party tool such as ShutUp10, https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10