# Windows 10: how to disable "Roblox" and other ads from start menu when the various anti-ad settings are already operative?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, advertisements

Today (August 2020) I opened the Start Menu in Windows 10 and typed the beginning of a program name, in order to launch the program. After a couple keystrokes a "Roblox" ad suddenly appeared beside the search results.

What's strange is that in `Settings -> Start`, the option *Show suggestions occasionally in Start* is **disabled**. Also all the settings described in the answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1348757/937189) have already been disabled. How come I'm seeing this ad then? Are there other anti-ad options that I need to set? The ad cannot be right-clicked.(Windows is reaching the ultimate bottom in professionality...).

Edit: I should have taken a snip of the ad. Now it isn't appearing any longer. But here's the rough position where it appeared, in red:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add some pictures to show which places the ads are coming up in?

Comment: That's weird, I've been using Windows 10 since release and never once saw an ad while searching. I guess you could use try using [Windows 10 Debloater](https://github.com/Sycnex/Windows10Debloater)

Comment: @CaldeiraG yes very weird – especially because the ad option was disabled... Thank you for the link.

Comment: I don't know who flagged this as duplicate – it isn't a duplicate: the settings mentioned in the other questions seem to have no effect.